# Return json body in REQUEST nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, httprequest

I'm using the `request` module to make an HTTP GET request to an url in order to get a JSON response.

However, my function is not returning the response's body.

Can someone please help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var body= getJson(req.params.id);
  res.send(body);
});
```

Here is my `getJson` function:

```
function getJson(myid){
  // Set the headers
  var headers = {
   'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
   'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
  // Configure the request
  var options = {
    url: 'http://www.XXXXXX.com/api/get_product.php',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    qs: {'id': myid}
  }

  // Start the request
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    return body;
  }
  else
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: and your get_product.php actually outputs JSON, right?

Comment: Have you tested this code against another similar service known to work?

Comment: @chris-l when i write console.log(body) instead of return body; it shows the json data in my logs

Comment: @tadman the URL works when I try it in my browser

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Unless you're going to deploy your browser, you need to test your NodeJS code. What you have here *should* work.

Comment: @tadman well body is empty and it doesn't show anything so there has to be something wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
res.send(body);
```

is being called before your getJson() function returns.

You can either pass a callback to getJson:

```
getJson(req.params.id, function(data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```

...and in the getjson function:

```
function getJson(myid, callback){
// Set the headers
var headers = {
'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
// Configure the request
var options = {
url: 'http://www.XXXXXX.com/api/get_product.php',
method: 'GET',
headers: headers,
qs: {'id': myid}
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    callback(body);
}
else
    console.log(error);
})  

}
```

or simply call:

```
res.json(getJson(req.params.id));
```

Comment: thank you so much. I also changed this line callback(body) to callback(JSON.parse(body)).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are doing a return, expecting that the router will get the content.

Since is an async callback, that will not work. You need to refactor your code to be async.

When you are doing `return body;` the function that is being returned is the callback of request, and in no part you are sending the body to the router.

Try this:

```
function getJson(myid, req, res) {
  var headers, options;

  // Set the headers
  headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

  // Configure the request
  options = {
    url: 'http://www.XXXXXX.com/api/get_product.php',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    qs: {'id': myid}
  }

  // Start the request
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(body);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

And this router:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  getJson(req.params.id, req, res);
});
```

Here, you are instead passing the `res` param to the `getJson` function, so the callback of request will be able to call it as soon as its able to do it.

Comment: how can I return the body to router then? I tried this but it doesnt work: var callback=request(....)   return callback;